# AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute. Can't call on another function's attribute

Tags: python, function, attributes

"order_total" works fine in the function it was created in (take_customer_order) but for some reason I can't call it in the new function I made.

```
    def take_customer_order():
    new_pizza = input("Order a pizza?  (Y/N) ")
    if new_pizza.upper() == "N":
        return print("Have a nice day.")
    if new_pizza.upper() != "Y" and new_pizza.upper() != "N":
        return print("I'll take that as a no.  Have a nice day.")
    size, meats, veg, quantity = get_pizza_info(size=0, meats=0, veg=0, quantity=0)
    if size == 1:
        size_cost = 6.50
    if size == 2:
        size_cost = 9.50
    if size == 3:
        size_cost = 11.50
    meats_cost = (meats - 1) * 3.50
    veg_cost = (veg - 1) * 1.50
    order_total = 0
    pizza_total = (size_cost + meats_cost + veg_cost * quantity)
    print("Pizza total: $", "{:,.2f}".format(pizza_total))
    order_total += pizza_total
    while new_pizza != "N":
        new_pizza = input("Order a pizza?  (Y/N) ")
        if new_pizza.upper() == "N":
            break
        get_pizza_info(size, meats, veg, quantity)
        print("Pizza total: $", "{:,.2f}".format(pizza_total))
        order_total += pizza_total
    print("Your total is $", "{:,.2f}".format(order_total))
    return order_total, pizza_total
```

Here is where I added a new function to hopefully make order_total global:

```
def make_order_total_global():
    take_customer_order.order_total()
    return take_customer_order.order_total()
```

this was the original code I had submitted, the one having issues calling order_total.

```
def run_roccos_pizza_shop():
    revenue = 0
    patron_num = 0
    while True:
        partynum = input("Enter number in party or 'Close' to quit. ")
        if partynum.upper() == "CLOSE":
            print("Have a nice day!")
            break
        else:
            patron_num += int(partynum)
        revenue += take_customer_order.order_total()
    print("Customers served: ", patron_num)
    print("Total revenue $", "{:,.2f}".format(revenue))
    return patron_num, revenue
```

And that's that.  apparently since my edit is mostly code, I need more details now.  Deets deeeties deeetily doooooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call the "take_customer_order.order_total ()" function because it has local visibility within the "take_customer_order ()" function and should have global visibility in order to be called. I recommend unpacking into two distinct functions in order to give global visibility to the "take_customer_order.order_total ()" function.

ex.
from:

```
def hi ():
    def hello ():
        print ("hello")
    hello ()

to:
def hello ():
    print ("hello")

def hi ():
    hello ()
```

Update:

Try this:

```
def make_order_total_global():
    return take_customer_order()[0]
```

Comment: I made another function and called take_customer_order.order_total() but it didn't make it visible

Comment: let me see the code please!

Comment: The important thing is that you can now call the function without any exceptions being raised

Comment: Ok, @Gaetano I edited my submission to show more code.  Thank you for your help

Comment: The value returned by the "take customer order ()" function is actually a tuple. To get just the "order_total" value you can simply write: return take_customer_order ()[0]

Comment: Before reading the entire code I didn't understand the extent of the real problem

Comment: Your problem was only to access only one return value of the function

Comment: Thanks so much!  revenue += take_customer_order()[0]  did the trick!

Comment: It was a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `take_customer_order` needs to return something...functions do not have attributes you can access outside of their scope.

Comment: take_customer_order does return order_total (at the end of its own function)

Comment: then saying `revenue += take_customer_order()` should solve your problem but when you call `take_customer_order()` it does not store whatever it returns in anything in the code above

Comment: When I do revenue += take_customer_order() it says I'm trying to use operand += for an int and tuple